# Initialize parametric-size array of parameterized derived type in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Fortran allows parametrizing the size of elements of derived types. However, where fixed-size elements can have a default value assigned in the type declaration, there doesn't seem to be a way for parametrized entries:

```
PROGRAM main
  IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE data1
     INTEGER :: array(5) = 2   ! allowed
  END type data1

  TYPE data2(n)
     INTEGER, LEN :: n
     INTEGER :: array(n) = 2   ! incorrect: error #8737 with intel fortran 19,
  END type data2               !            ignored by gfortran 8.2.1

END PROGRAM main
```

Assigning default values is convenient, as it allows avoiding repeating the initialization every time the type is used, but for parametric-sized fields it isn't allowed; Gfortran just ignores the default value silently, and Intel Fortran issues an error

```
error #8737: For a default initialized component every type parameter and array bound
             must be a constant expression.   [ARRAY]
```

Is there any syntax, that would allow defining a default value after all?

Answer (score 2):

There can be no default initialization for such components.

As the Intel Fortran error message states, the array bounds for a component with an initialization expression must be constant expressions (this is constraint C762 of Fortran 2018).  The length type parameter is not usable as a constant expression.

There is no other syntax to specify a default value for the component.

A kind type parameter can feature in a constant expression, so components with bounds given by a kind parameter of that type can have default initialization.

Comment: Are you sure?  F2018, page 75, Note 3, seems to disagree.

Comment: @evets, I'm afraid I don't have access to my final standard document at the moment, but the draft version I've checked has no array component in Note 3. Could you provide more detail on which part you mean? (I see that it has a non-constant length character component with default initialization but I assume that was a mistake that's corrected in the final version.)

Comment: Note 3, contains `TYPE MEMBER (NAME_LEN) ; INTEGER, LEN :: NAME_LEN ; CHARACTER (LEN = NAME_LEN) :: NAME = '' ; ...`  This shows component initialization where a type parameter is used in the specification expression.  The standard explicitly states __A type parameter may be used as a primary in a specification expression (10.1.11) in the derived-type-def.__  If one goes to 10.1.11, it then has __A restricted expression is an expression ... and each primary is ... (13) a type parameter of the derived type being defined,__

Comment: @evets, I'm afraid I don't see the relevance of specification expressions to the initialization of components.  The use of non-constant `name_len` as a specification expression for character component length naturally is allowed when `name_len` is a type parameter of the type being defined with that component. But specification expressions aren't what matters when it comes to default initialization. C762 is an additional constraint which means the type parameters and array bounds must be constant expressions, not specification expressions.

Comment: You're missing `NAME = ''`.  `NAME` is being initialized to a 0 length string.

Comment: I do see `character(name_len) :: name=''`.  But I also see C762 which has to win if there's a conflict between it and an example in a note (even if the note is normative). What is your view of C762 and why does it not apply in this case?

Comment: It may come down to defining a type and using the defined type.  In Note 3,  you'll find `TYPE (MEMBER(9)) :: ORGANIZER = MEMBER (9) ("I. Manage",1,5,NULL ( ))`  The `9` is assigned to `NAME_LEN`, and then `"I. Manage"` is assigned to `NAME`.   Explanatory text in Note 3, then is:  `ORGANIZER` is explicitly initialized, overriding the default initialization for an object of type `MEMBER`.  I'll also note that it is called a **parameterized** derived type, which suggests that `NAME_LEN` is treated somewhat like a `PARAMETER`, i.e., a named constant.

Comment: The constraint and the example of Note 3 in the draft standard do conflict.  However, the simplest resolution must be that `name_len` should be a kind parameter rather than a length parameter (this would be consistent with the constraint and internally within the note). There's no change that simple for C762 which retains its value as an additional explicit constraint and relevance to this question.

Comment: I have sent an email to J3 asking about a possible conflict between Note 3 and C762.  I think C762 can be modified to **C762 (R737) If component-initialization appears, every type parameter and array bound of the component shall be a colon, constant expression, or a type-param-name.**

Comment: An official inquiry may mean an official interp and that takes months. Or do I confuse that with WG5? A quick question on comp.lang.fortran is often faster.

Comment: @evets, please do inform us of any response. That said, I think that addition is a significant change which I find hard to believe is in keeping with the intention of the standard (and as an accidental omission).

Comment: Is character length really a type parameter? @francescalus Omissions of such kind happened before and were resolved by interps. But that is a rather lengthy process.

Comment: @VladimirF, character length is indeed a type parameter (see, for example, 7.2 p3).

Comment: @VladimirF, I agree that this could have been omitted by mistake and the intention was to allow `integer :: array(n)=0` (but not `integer :: array(n+0)=0`, `integer :: array(2:n+1)=0` or `integer :: array(n)=[(i,i=1,n)]`) but I feel mistakenly having the length parameter non-constant in the example seems much more likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor that takes the length parameter to create the object

```
module datatypes

type data2(n)
    integer, len :: n
    integer :: array(n)
contains        
    procedure, pass :: data2_fill2
end type

interface data2
    module procedure new_data2
end interface

contains
    subroutine data2_fill2(this)
        class(data2(*)) :: this
        this%array = 2
    end subroutine
    function new_data2(n) result(r)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        type(data2(n)) :: r
        call r%data2_fill2()
    end function
end module

program Main
use datatypes
    type(data2(3)) :: mydata

    mydata = data2(100)

    print *, "Size of array ", size(mydata%array)

    if( mydata%array(1) /= 2) then
        print *, "Something went wrong"
    end if


end program
```

Comment: Why so complicated?  The standard already allows component initialization.

Comment: This method doesn't allow the compact, non-redundant initialization of fields to sensible values (as opposed to uninitialized memory), that I am looking for. Most notably, it doesn't guarantee initialization regardless of usage of the type, as default values do.

Answer (score 0):

You have found a bug in different compilers.  Your code is standard conforming.  Fleshing out the code a bit, the following should print '2 2 2'.

```
program main

implicit none
!
! F2018, 7.5.1, page 64: A derived type can be parameterized by one or
! more type parameters, each of which is defined to be either a kind
! or length type parameter and can have a default value.
!
! F2018, 7.5.3.1, page 69: A type parameter may be used as a primary in
! a specification expression (10.1.11) in the derived-type-def.
!
! 10.1.11 Specification expression (page 156)
! ...
!    R1028 specification-expr  is scalar-int-expr
!
! C1010 (R1028) The scalar-int-expr shall be a restricted expression.
!
! A restricted expression is an expression in which each operation is
! intrinsic or defined by a specification function and each primary is
! ...
! (13) a type parameter of the derived type being defined,
!
type data2(n)
   integer, len :: n
   integer :: array(n) = 2
end type data2

type(data2(n=3)) :: a

print *, a%array  ! This should print 2 2 2

end program main
```

gfortran compiles the code, but prints '0 0 0', so
gfortran has a bug in applying the component initialization.

Comment: Please see my answer and the comments there to see why I think this answer is wrong. However, I'll add here that one cannot look at rules in isolation. The use of a length type parameter in a specification expression is uncontroversial (to the extent that it's hard to see why we'd even have length parameters without that ability), but specification expressions do not appear in the context of default initialization. 7.5.3.1 allows us to have a component `integer :: array(n)` (for `n` a length parameter) but it says nothing about default initialization which is subject to further constraint.